# What is the best video format to convert to for all mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, video

I am needing to convert video's to put on my website but I need to be able to get the right format so that they can be viewed on all mobile devices, the problem I am having is that I cannot get them to work on android. Does android required a different encoder? is there a format in which I can use that will work on on mobiles

- Blackberry
- Android
- iOS (iPhone/iPad)

Comment: I Think you best bet is 3GP for all mobile devices, as codecs like H.264 only work on certain android devices depending on their firmware etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mp4 cointainer,15 fps, 640x480 resolution is pretty generic
Though not very good quality with the low frame rate, but it will probably be supported by most devices.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Android Media Fortmats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#recommendations) docs you need MPEG-4 container and H.264 Baseline Profile codec with 480 x 360 px resolution, 30 fps, video bitrate 500 Kbps, audio codec AAC-LC with bitrate 128 Kbps

Answer (score 0):

.m4v is listed under Squeeze's encode list for iphone and android, yet it also worked on the desktop/chrome/safari/firefox as well.